# CryptDecryptMessage returns CRYPT_E_NO_DECRYPT_CERT when executed inside service running under LSA

Tags: c, windows, service, certificate, cryptoapi

I created an RSA Certificate with a Private Key in LocalMachine/My store.

I then created a simple Windows console app in C to:

- locate the cert by thumbprint
- encrypt a buffer with `CryptEncryptMessage`
- write the buffer out to a file

I then wrote a small service app, also in C to:

- read the buffer
- decrypt with `CryptDecryptMessage`

It all works fine as long as the service app is not running under the Local System Account (LSA). In that case, `CryptDecryptMessage` generates `CRYPT_E_NO_DECRYPT_CERT (0x8009200C)`. This is despite that the Cert is in LocalMachine/My

I tried to strip down the code as much as possible but it is still rather long. I'm hoping there is some flag setting I am getting wrong. Or is this expected behavior? Thanks for taking a look.

## Windows console app

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    HCERTSTORE hSysStore = NULL;
    DWORD err;
    PCHAR    certThumbprint   = "14FE20556FC106DA4C561707ABDFEACEB8CAAC98";
    PCERT_CONTEXT pContext = NULL;
    BYTE*    pbEncryptedBlob = NULL;
    DWORD    cbEncryptedBlob;
    BYTE bPlain[255] = {0};
    DWORD cbContent;
    strcpy_s(bPlain, sizeof(bPlain)-1, argv[1]);
    cbContent = strlen(bPlain)+1;
    err = myGetCertFromThumb(CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"MY", certThumbprint, &hSysStore, &pContext);
    if (err != 0)
        goto cleanup;
    pbEncryptedBlob = malloc(BUF_SZ);
    cbEncryptedBlob = BUF_SZ;
    /**** code below ****/
    err = myEncryptMsg(pContext, bPlain, cbContent, pbEncryptedBlob, &cbEncryptedBlob);
    if (err != 0)
        goto cleanup;
    printf("Encrypted msg size=%d\n", cbEncryptedBlob);

    /****  write cbEncryptedBlob to file  ****/

cleanup:
    if (pbEncryptedBlob)
        free(pbEncryptedBlob);
    if (pContext)
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pContext);
    if (hSysStore != NULL)
        CertCloseStore(hSysStore, CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG);
    return(err);
}

DWORD myEncryptMsg(PCERT_CONTEXT pContext, BYTE* pbPlain, DWORD cbPlainszsz, BYTE* pbCipher, DWORD *pcbCiphersz)
{
    BOOL rc;
    DWORD err;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT RecipientCertArray[1];
    DWORD EncryptAlgSize;
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
    CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER EncryptAlgorithm;
    CRYPT_ENCRYPT_MESSAGE_PARA EncryptParams;
    DWORD EncryptParamsSize;
    rc = CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,        // Address for handle to be returned.
        NULL,               // Use the current user's logon name.
        NULL,               // Use the default provider.
        PROV_RSA_FULL,      // Need to both encrypt and sign.
        0);              // No flags needed.
    if (rc) 
        goto keyset_exists;
    err = GetLastError();
    if (err != NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
        goto cleanup;
    rc = CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,        // Address for handle to be returned.
        NULL,               // Use the current user's logon name.
        NULL,               // Use the default provider.
        PROV_RSA_AES,      // Need to both encrypt and sign.
        CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);              // No flags needed.
    if (!rc) 
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        goto cleanup;
    }
keyset_exists:
    RecipientCertArray[0] = pContext;
    EncryptAlgSize = sizeof(EncryptAlgorithm);
    memset(&EncryptAlgorithm, 0, EncryptAlgSize);
    EncryptAlgorithm.pszObjId = szOID_NIST_AES256_CBC;
    EncryptParamsSize = sizeof(EncryptParams);
    memset(&EncryptParams, 0, EncryptParamsSize);
    EncryptParams.cbSize =  EncryptParamsSize;
    EncryptParams.dwMsgEncodingType = (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING);
    EncryptParams.hCryptProv = hCryptProv;
    EncryptParams.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptAlgorithm;
    rc = CryptEncryptMessage(
        &EncryptParams,
        1,
        RecipientCertArray,
        pbPlain,
        cbPlainszsz,
        pbCipher,
        pcbCiphersz);
    if (!rc)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        goto cleanup;
    }
    err = 0;
cleanup:
    if(hCryptProv)
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv,0);
    return(err);
}
```

## Windows Service App

```
BYTE * someRoutineInsideService()
{
    DWORD err;
    BYTE*    pbEncryptedBlob = NULL;
    DWORD    cbEncryptedBlob;
    BYTE* pbDecryptedMessage = NULL;
    DWORD cbDecryptedMessage;
    pbEncryptedBlob = malloc(BUF_SZ);
    cbEncryptedBlob = BUF_SZ;

    /**** read pbEncryptedBlob from file ****/

    pbDecryptedMessage = malloc(BUF_SZ);
    cbDecryptedMessage = BUF_SZ;
    /**** code below ****/
    err = myDecryptMessage("MY", pbEncryptedBlob, cbEncryptedBlob, pbDecryptedMessage, &cbDecryptedMessage);
    if (err != 0)
        goto cleanup;
cleanup:
    if (pbEncryptedBlob)
        free(pbEncryptedBlob);
    return(pbDecryptedMessage);
}

DWORD myDecryptMessage(LPSTR cStore, BYTE *pbEncryptedBlob, DWORD cbEncryptedBlob, BYTE *pbDecryptedMessage, DWORD *cbDecryptedMessage)
{
    HCERTSTORE CertStoreArray[1];
    CRYPT_DECRYPT_MESSAGE_PARA  DecryptParams;
    DWORD  DecryptParamsSize = sizeof(DecryptParams);
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = 0;                      // CSP handle
    HCERTSTORE hStoreHandle = 0;
    DWORD err = 0;
    BOOL rc;
    rc = CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,        // Address for handle to be returned.
        NULL,               // Use the current user's logon name.
        NULL,               // Use the default provider.
        PROV_RSA_FULL,      // Need to both encrypt and sign.
        0);              // No flags needed.
    if (!rc)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        goto cleanup;
    }
    hStoreHandle = CertOpenSystemStore(hCryptProv, cStore);
    if (hStoreHandle == NULL)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        goto cleanup;
    }
    CertStoreArray[0] = hStoreHandle;
    memset(&DecryptParams, 0, DecryptParamsSize);
    DecryptParams.cbSize = DecryptParamsSize;
    DecryptParams.dwMsgAndCertEncodingType = (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING);
    DecryptParams.cCertStore = 1;
    DecryptParams.rghCertStore = CertStoreArray;
    rc = CryptDecryptMessage(
              &DecryptParams,
              pbEncryptedBlob,
              cbEncryptedBlob,
              pbDecryptedMessage,
              cbDecryptedMessage,
              NULL);
    if (!rc)
    {
        err = GetLastError();    
        /**** returns 0x8009200C (CRYPT_E_NO_DECRYPT_CERT) if service run under LSA ****/
        goto cleanup;
    }
cleanup:
    if(hCryptProv)
        rc = CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv,0);
    return(err);
}
```

Comment: in your call `CryptAcquireContext` you use *pszContainer* as `NULL` - so default key container name is used. but this is different between user and service. you need use concrete name. not 0 here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You mean choose any unique container name? I read the remarks at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta] (CryptAcquireContext) but it wasn't clear to me what it is supposed to be set to.

Comment: but you can get `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` from cerificat via `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` and use *pwszContainerName, pwszProvName, dwProvType*

Comment: really you not need call `CryptAcquireContext` at all. in encrypt `EncryptParams.hCryptProv` - *This member is not used and should be set to NULL.* in decrypt - your error in call `CertOpenSystemStore(hCryptProv, cStore);` but instead you need open the same store as in encrypt - `CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"MY")` and code will be much more simply

Comment: you can you something like https://pastebin.com/kLZxYWZa

Comment: @RbMm - thanks for the sample code. It works if both the encrypt and decrypt are done in the same program. But if the encrypt is done in one program and the decrypt in another I still get `CRYPT_E_NO_DECRYPT_CERT (0x8009200C)` from `CryptDecryptMessage`.

Comment: ok, i special check [this code](https://pastebin.com/CSQnW9i2) when run `DecryptMsg` from exe started with *lsass.exe* as parent process (under *LocalSystem* token) and all work correct. `CRYPT_E_NO_DECRYPT_CERT` say that you open store where no certificat which used to encode message. so you open different stores in encode and decode process. but if use say `CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"MY")` - will be the same store